# fixed width div next to div with Swiper causes weird behavior

Tags: html, css, flexbox, semantic-ui

I really couldn't find a better title for my problem, but I hope I'll explain it better here.

So what I want is a div (240px) next to a div that contains a Swiper slider which needs to fill the remaining width.

The problem is that Swiper's wrapper has like 4800px or something (I guess it's the total width of all the slides) and when using Flexbox with `flex: 1` on the filling div, it doesn't stop at the container's width but instead continues and goes out of the window, thus the slider doesn't work properly.

Here is a jsFiddle to see the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kgcggf3u/4/

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the wrapping container - `#homepage-slider`. It seems to work fine now: https://jsfiddle.net/kgcggf3u/27/